# Right Aligned TextBlock with TextWrapping wraps at Left Side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to have a TextBlock align text where multiple lines are on the right side. Currently, the behavior is that the text is aligned to the right for the first line, however the second line starts on the left side. Is there a way to have wrapped lines also align to the right?

`<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="txtLeft" Text="the key for the value is two lines+" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [TextAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property.

Comment: I had same prob! but TextAlignment solved it. Thanks dude. +1